# Как считать файл в массив?

Tags: java

У меня есть объект типа File, как можно его считать в массив Byte?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Получаем размер файла
    long length = file.length();

    // Создаем массив для хранения данных
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    // Считываем
    int offset = 0;

    int numRead = 0;

    while (offset < bytes.length
        && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {

        offset += numRead;
    }

    // Проверяем, все ли прочитано
    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }

    // Закрываем и возвращаем
    is.close();

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Точно не уверен, но вроде бы так. Если где-то ошибка, то подправьте.

Comment: Ну, в качестве примера сгодится. Только задача сама по себе безумие

Comment: пример "безумия":
1) сжать данные
2) зашифровать паролем
3) помехоустойчивое кодирование

Answer (score 2):

```
public static byte[] read( File file ) throws IOException
{
    int length;
    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream( file );

    while( (length = in.read( tmp )) >= 0 )
    {
        out.write( tmp, 0, length );
    }

    return out.toByteArray( );
}
```

Comment: Предыдущее решение лучше, хотя и немного длиннее.