# Как считать определенное количество символов из файла?

Tags: java

В файле записаны два числа, допустим 5 и 8, и далее идет двухмерная матрица. Как на основе этих чисел, считать определенное количество символов данной матрицы? Допустим в данном случае нужно считать матрицу размером 5 на 8. А все, что после нее пропустить

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблемы? В чтении определенного числа байт из файла?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Немного исправил вопрос

Comment: Все равно не ясно в чем проблема: в чтении из файла определенного количества байт? Или в чем?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, каким образом можно реализовать считывание определенного кол-ва байт

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6572/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2

Comment: Вообщето стэковерфлоу не для решения домашнего задания по этому голосую за закрытие. А так всё просто двойной цикл 5 по 8, и считываете каждый символ по отдельности или формируете массив этих символов.

Comment: Данные в файле в текстовом виде или в двоичном?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    String[] params = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
    int m = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);

    System.out.println(n + "x" + m);

    reader
            .lines()
            .limit(m)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```