# как вставить в html переменную javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Справочник Android</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AndroidHelp\AndroidHelp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">
            <ul>
               <li><a class="active" href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
               <li><a href="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           </ul>    
        </div><div id="right"></div>
    </div>


    <iframe id="iframe" src="AndroidHelp\HTML\1.html"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на пункт меню. в iframe отобразилась ссылка из нажатого пункта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого не нужен javascript, достаточно определить для iframe атрибут name, а ссылкам атрибут target равный имени iframe:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a target="question" href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559163/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-html-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-javascript">как вставить в html переменную javascript?</a></li>
    <li><a target="question" href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559162/div-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0">div, который прилипает к низу браузера</a></li>
    <li><a target="question" href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558965/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0">Как считать определенное количество символов из файла?</a></li>
</ul>    

<iframe name="question" />
```